# Matplotlib set year on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

i would like to have a plot of nasdaq market index that has on x axis the years since 1971 and on y axis the values.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('nasdaq-historical-chart.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values

df = pd.read_csv('nasdaq-historical-chart.csv',parse_dates=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
plt.plot(dataset)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.plot(df['year'], dataset)
plt.title('NASDAQ historical chart',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Value',fontsize=14)
plt.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=14)
plt.show()
```

In this way i have the right plot but without years on x axis
[image]

If i put:

```
plt.plot(df['year'], dataset)
```

i have:
[image]

why the plot changed? How can i modify it?

Comment: Each year has more than one data point. For example the value for January of 1999 will be plotted at the same 'x' position as the value for February 1999. Try plotting with ```plt.plot(df['date'],dataset)```

Comment: @SixenseMan same plot :(

Comment: Can you post some data?

Comment: @Joe https://ibb.co/zPVMppP
here the pic

Comment: @Joe did you see the data?

Comment: @FabioG please check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I created some data similar to yours as example, and you can do in a similar way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1971-1-1','1971-1-2','1971-1-3','1971-1-4','1971-1-5','1971-1-6','1971-1-7','1971-1-8','1971-1-9',
                       '1971-1-10', '1971-1-11', '1971-1-12', '1972-1-1','1972-1-2','1972-1-3','1972-1-4',
                       '1972-1-5','1972-1-6','1972-1-7','1972-1-8','1972-1-9','1972-1-10', '1972-1-11', '1972-1-12'],
                   'values':[150, 130, 100, 95, 100, 105, 200, 180, 170, 160, 150, 155, 155, 170, 190, 192, 195, 200, 220,
                        230, 220, 210, 230, 235]})
print (df)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m')
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.plot(df['date'], df['values'])
plt.title('NASDAQ historical chart',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Value',fontsize=14)
plt.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Still the same for me :( here is the dataset: https://www.macrotrends.net/1320/nasdaq-historical-chart